# cron job for deleting records on firebase cloud functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a Firestore database that consists of records with an "endDate" field. Based on this field I want to delete some records once a day and run a cron job for them. For example, if today is November 22, 2023 and the end date is November 21, 2023, I want that record to be removed from the database. How can I achieve this? Thank you

Comment: Your post is about to be closed. Read this [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so that you understand why.

Answer (score 2):

You can leverage Firestore's [Time-To-Live feature](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/ttl) to have the system automatically remove "stale" documents.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a firebase cloud function that for example runs Node.js code everyday at 0:00.

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");    

exports.deleteEntries = functions.pubsub.schedule("0 0 * * *")
    .onRun(() => {
    //delete here
})
```

"0 0 * * *" is a cron expression, [examples](https://crontab.guru/examples.html)

One job lies way in the capacity of cloud functions' free tier too.